# How to index without mapping type

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new in ElasticSearch, reading the documentation of the version 6.1 say that mapping type will be deleted for version 7. My question is how I can index a document without type? Could you give some example please.

Answer (score 2):

In elasticsearch 6 you still need to provide type, though it's recommended a type name to be "_doc"

> Indices created in 6.x only allow a single-type per index. Any name
>   can be used for the type, but there can be only one. The preferred
>   type name is _doc, so that index APIs have the same path as they will
>   have in 7.0: PUT {index}/_doc/{id} and POST {index}/_doc

Look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/removal-of-types.html#_schedule_for_removal_of_mapping_types) for more.